# I can't get this foreignkey table value to be displayed in the django template

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-templates, foreign-keys

I cant get some ForeignKey values displayed in my template. This are the two models involved in the question:

** Models.py **

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null= True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length= 300, null= True)

class Spotify_Playlist(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null= True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    spotify_url = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length= 100, null= True)
    artist_img = models.ImageField(null= True, upload_to= 'image/')
```

*** Admin.py ***

```
@admin.register(Portfolio)
class PortfolioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SpotyListInline,
        SpotySingleInline,
        YoutubeInline,
    ]

class SpotyListInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Spotify_Playlist
```

So Im trying to display the spotify playlist in my template like this

*** index.html ***

```
 <section id="portfolio">
                {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
                    <h1>{{ portfolio.title }}</h1>
                    <p>{{ portfolio.description }}</p>
                    {% for playlist in portfolio.Spotify_Playlist_set.all %}
                        <p>{{playlist.title}}</p>
                        <iframe src='https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/{{ playlist.spotify_url }}'
                        width="50%" height="380" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                    {% endfor %}    
                {% endfor %}
            </section>
```

But the {{playlist.title}} and the embeded player with the {{playlist.spotify_url}} aren't showing.
I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default reverse relationship name is in lowercase. Try:

```
{% for playlist in portfolio.spotify_playlist_set.all %}
```

From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward:

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, **lowercased**. This Manager returns QuerySets, which can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving objects” section above.

Comment: That was it ! Thanks a lot, I'm pretty much a begginer, and the course I took didn't explain what you just explained to me. Thanks again :)